# [symfony]connection register on the same page?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, authentication, connection

I do have a problem with my symfony code, I'm actually searching how to put two forms, one for connections and one for login on the same page and this shows me error if I submit the register form, because it is the specified page in security.yaml :
here is the code for my register form...

```php
class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="register_login")
     */
    public function register(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $hasher,
    Request $request, ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $userInfos = new UserInfos();        
        $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationType::class, $userInfos);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            $userInfos->setLastConnection(new \DateTime());
            $userInfos->setSubscribedAt(new \DateTime());
            $userInfos->setPassword($hasher->encodePassword($userInfos,
            $userInfos->getPassword()));
            $manager->persist($userInfos);
            $manager->flush();
        }
        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', [
            'formUser' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
}
```

and it returns the twig file with the login form...

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="{{ path('register_login') }}" method="post">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" required type="email" name="_username" placeholder="Email">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" required type="password" name="_password" placeholder="Mot de passe">
            <button class="btn btn-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Connexion</button>
        </form>
```

My security.yaml config: 
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\UserInfos:
            algorithm: bcrypt

```
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    in_memory: { memory: ~ }
    DB:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\UserInfos
            property: email
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: true
        provider: DB
        form_login:
            login_path: register_login
            check_path: register_login
```

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Welcome to the forums. It is difficult to understand what exactly is your scenario and problem here. I.e. you talk about having two forms on one page and you have code of processing just one - and you talk about register form and have code about login action. And if you do get some error when trying to do something, please include the error here in your question as well.

Comment: Yeah sorry it wasn't clear, both forms are working now but not on the same page, it throw an error because in my security.yaml at login and check_path I got the page that contains both forms, my error: 
"The key "_username" must be a string, "NULL" given." ("_username" is the name of my input to login)
Sorry if I'm not explaining it well

Comment: The second form is directly (the one to login) is directly in my html.twig file

Comment: ok, in that case I would suggest that you just google "symfony two forms in one page" first as that question has been asked and answered many times :) If you cannot find any solution to your particular problem, then it would be good update your question with all the relevant data (both the form processing actions, how your twig files look like (i.e. are the forms separate or is there one form with two actions) etc etc)

Answer (score 0):

You put 2 form in twig, you must put the form in one controller (may be register)

Put $formRegister->createView(); $formLogin->createView() in your template.

the action of one form is in {{ path('register...') }} and login in {{ path('login') }}

but pay attention you must control all variable else its show you an error